# Keras создать модель и одновременно обучать её на разных параметрах

Tags: python, keras

Я новичок в Keras, я написал простую модель на keras, допустим я хочу проверить какой шаг обучения найлучший, у меня есть масив с шагами для обучения, и я хочу одновременно запустить ету модель с разними параметрами и выбрать наилучший,как это лучше всего сделать?